# ReactJs How to change an icon of a button on the click event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the `IconButton` from [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button) and I want to change the icon of the button after the click/touch event.

```
var tableModeElement =
<IconButton key="tableModeButton" 
 onTouchTap={() => { 
   this.setState(prevState => (
    { isCardView: !prevState.isCardView })) } }>
  <i className="material-icons theme-color-p1">
   {this.state.isCardView ? "view_module" : "list"}
  </i>
</IconButton>
```

The expression `{this.state.isCardView ? "view_module" : "list"}` is only evaluated once and no more after that. I thought if I change the state I will force a re-render? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: added that the iconButton is assigned to a variable. If I include the `<IconButton>` directly into the render method it works fine. I had to re-assign the variable to make it work.

Comment: Maybe it could help, if you tell us which icon set you use and how you want to integrate it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this would work:

```
class IconButton extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isCardView: false,
    }
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <a className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>this.setState({ isCardView: !this.state.isCardView })}>
        { this.state.isCardView
          ? <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" />
          : <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" />
        }
        &nbsp;&nbsp;BUTTON
      </a>
    );
  }

}

class App extends React.Component { 
  render () {                                        
    return (
      <div>
        <IconButton />  
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

I'm using bootstrap, but any icon system would work

http://codepen.io/cjke/pen/MJvXNo?editors=0010

Comment: This probably works fine. I had some logic errors in my structure. I need to force the re-render by calling it manually since it's stored in a variable.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you storing it in a variable? 9 times out of 10, forcing a re-render isn't needed with a little bit of cleaning up

Comment: It's part of a bigger UI and to keep things modular. That's Button basically belongs to the Header.

Comment: Ah ok - so "isCardView" is actually the state of the header, not an individual button?

Answer (score 2):

Setting text "view_module" or "list" in a `<i>` element will not change the icon for the button

You need to have a nested icon within the button, eg:

```
<IconButton key="tableModeButton" 
 onTouchTap={() => { 
   this.setState({
     isCardView: !this.state.isCardView
   })
  }}>
   {this.state.isCardView ? <IconA /> : <IconB /> }
</IconButton>
```

Comment: Try it with the different set state call i just edited

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could come up with :

```
     <IconButton key="tableModeButton" onTouchTap={(e) => { 

        let show = this.state.prevState.isCardView;
        let index = show.indexOf('show');

        if (index != -1) {
           show = 'hide';
        } else {
           show = 'show';
        }

        this.setState(prevState => ({ isCardView: show }));
        event.preventDefault()

} }>
```

Comment: This is not really what I am searching for. I don't want to hide it. More like flip the icon.

Comment: In fact the names I used are examples you can use your own class, I only wanted to show the principle :)

Answer (score 1):

The icon to be used by `<IconButton>` is defined by it's iconClassName prop.

It could look something like this afterwards.

```
<IconButton key="tableModeButton" 
  onTouchTap={() => { 
     this.setState( prevState => {isCardView: !prevState.isCardView} ) }
  }
  iconClassName={this.state.isCardView ? "view_module" : "list"} />
</IconButton>
```